# What are the low hanging fruit for optimizing google app engine with respect to quota usage?

Tags: google-app-engine

Everyone learns to use Memcache pretty quick. Another one I've learned recently is setting indexed=False for Model properties that I am not going to query against. What are some others? What are the *big* ones?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `offset` in queries. Use cursors instead.

   Explanations: offset loads all data up to offset+limit and charges you for it, but only returns limit entities.
2. Minimize instance use, by tweaking [idle instances and pending latency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances) appropriately for your app.

Answer (score 1):

A couple helped us (not all may be low-hanging at first). First, we denormalized our datastore to reduce joins. I'm using SQL terms because I came from a SQL background. By spreading commonly queried elements around, we reduced the number of reads we had to make considerably, even after factoring in Memcache. Potentially increases writes but for most apps, the number of reads far outweighs the number of writes.

Next, we started using task queues, backends, and the channel API more often. I don't remember specific examples but I do remember we were able to reduce our front-end usage down below the free quota mark by moving some processing around to queues and backends and by sending data down via channel rather than having the client poll.

Also, we use objectify for our data access which we configure to automatically use memcache wherever appropriate.